# How to setup an TCP/IP proxy with traffic interception, for MS SQL traffic in this case

Tags: sql-server, proxy, squid, tcpip

I would like to setup an MS SQL proxy server.

It should forward all requests 1:1 and make it possible to log them, and modify some of the requests or answers according to some replacement rules I setup.

Maybe some TCP IP networking software or general proxy can do this, but even better some specialised MS SQL tools.

We are still on SQL Server 2005

Comment: Why would a 'specialised MS SQL Tool' be better?

Comment: @GregAskew Have a look at explunit's answer, he explains that the traffic is binary. A speciialised tool could analyse the binary content and understand or log/show/filter its text representation or even replace parts of it and reconvert.

Comment: I found this question regarding http traffic, but maybe there is a better solution for this setup. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-can-i-intercept-and-modify-http-requests

Comment: There is a similar question in reverse engineering Q&A but looking to log the queries intercepting the application instead of using a network tool: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/server-side-query-interception-with-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unlikely to work with standard networking software and regexes, since SQL Server uses binary protocol [Tabular Data Stream (TDS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream).

You would probably need a specialized application using something like [FreeTDS](http://freetds.schemamania.org/) or [jTDS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/) to decode, modify, forward, and respond to the requests.

If security is your concern, there are several commercial products offering database firewall features. For example, [Audit Vault and Database Firewall](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/security/audit-vault-database-firewall/overview/index.html) from Oracle (yes it works with SQL Server too) or [Database Firewall](http://www.greensql.com/database-firewall/) from GreenSQL.

From an architecture perspective, if this is a brand new application being envisioned, you may want to look at **not** exposing the SQL server directly but handling this kind of logic at the web service layer.

EDIT: it's possible to have SQL Server use HTTP endpoints (SOAP) for specific items, but this feature is deprecated and was [removed in SQL 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707789%28v=sql.110%29), so you should not count on it as a well-supported feature. Their recommendation is to handle this at the web service layer using WCF.

Comment: Regarding the security of the connection, it is already in a secure environment. But maybe we could use the oracle firewall tool in another setup some day. Looks promsing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to configure SQL Server to use text instead of binary?

Comment: added text above re http endpoints. I'm not an expert on the SQL firewall products, but I suspect they have a lot of logging features.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using SQL Server 2005 with the application

Comment: I just noticed that the oracle product has a "substitute" mode. And it works on sybase, which means it could operate correctly on MS SQL 2005. I am going to try out what it can do for me